# wxGLCanvas Pause Paint Event?

Tags: opengl, thread-safety, wxwidgets

In a application with data shared between wxGLCanvas and wxThreads.

**Scenario :** thread modifies the data which is used by canvas which results in a crash in paint event.

**Current Solution :** used mutex to share the data between canvas and thread.

**Issue :** we are displaying progress info of thread in a dialog. mutex locks main thread and the progress info dialog hangs.

**Constraint :** our data is huge and its costly to do copy. Canvas should not be cleared.

Any solution for my issue?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the data in chunks so the main thread has a chance to run periodically (ensure the data is coherent between chunks).

Otherwise send events to the main thread with the information to change the data. No information is changed on the worker thread but instead the main thread does the actual changing based on the calculation performed by the worker thread.